# Python how to access subfolder of subfolders

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I have trouble accessing the math text-files within the subfolders.

[image: Hierarchy of the folder]

This is the code I have written so far:

```
import os, sys
for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk(my_directory):
   for special_file in files:
      if special_file == 'math.txt'
         file_path = os.path.join(folder, special_file)
         with open(file_path, 'r+') as read_file
            counter += 1
            print('Reading math txt file' + str(counter))

            for line in read_file:
               print(line)
```

I am not able to do print lines of all the `math.txt` files within all the classes and all the schools and all the zones.

Before I had a version of the script that merged all the files, but some of the log files were extremely large (combined > 16GB).

Comment: Are you getting an error? (besides missing a `:` after the line where you open the file, and after the `special_file` test line)

Comment: What error are you getting? Or what is the output? There are some syntax errors in there, but I'm assuming that is just due to copy paste stuff, yeah?

Comment: Also, `counter` hasn't been initialised to 0.

Comment: jdi, i forgot that-thanks for the catch,RocketDonkey- i was printing the folders instead of the actual files, @MRAB thanks for the catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work for me. Only changes were those that @jdi, @MRAB and I were indicating - missing colons and initializing the `counter` variable. Since you're on Windows, you may want to make sure that you're properly specifying your directory path.

```
import os, sys

# Specify directory
# In your case, you may want something like the following
my_directory = 'C:/Users/<user_name>/Documents/ZoneA'

# Define the counter
counter = 1

# Start the loop
for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk(my_directory):
  for special_file in files:
    if special_file == 'math.txt':
      file_path = os.path.join(folder, special_file)

      # Open and read
      with open(file_path, 'r+') as read_file:
        print('Reading math txt file ' + str(counter))

        # Print the file
        for line in read_file:
           print(line)

        # Increment the counter
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Just use forward slashes for paths, even on windows.

Comment: @jdi Ha, all this time I was thinking 'There must be a better way'. Thanks for the awesome tip! Fixing now.

Comment: Haha, ya its nice to know its universally handled. +1 now that you have fixed that!

Comment: Haha, thanks man. Stoked about not having to double-slash stuff anymore!

Comment: Yes the forward slashes is very nice for paths...thanks again